# Draw nodes in ring form

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to use this drawing of a neural network and extend it to a recurrent neural network. To do so I'd like to arrange the *hidden* nodes to a ring and connect every hidden node with the other hidden nodes. This is a simple feed forward network I got from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/). Could someone show me how I can accomplish what I need?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-3] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

[image]

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is somehow unclear what you are asking. Do you want to have multiple hidden layers? Then how about output layer connections. I did something based on my understanding of your question. Please comment if it is not exactly what you want. My answer is based on your own code and [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/complete-graph/) example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[topaths]

\newcount\mycount
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % input layer
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

    % hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \number in {1,...,6}{
        \mycount=\number
        \advance\mycount by -1
        \multiply\mycount by 60
        \advance\mycount by 0
        \node[xshift=5cm, yshift=-2.5cm, hidden neuron] (N-\number) at (\the\mycount:3cm) {};
    }

    % hidden layer interconnections
    \foreach \number in {1,...,5}{
        \mycount=\number
        \advance\mycount by 1
        \foreach \numbera in {\the\mycount,...,6}{
            \path (N-\number) edge[<->] (N-\numbera);
        }
    }

    % output layer
    \node[xshift=10cm, yshift=-2.5cm,output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}] (O) {};

    % input-hidden-output connections
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \foreach \dest in {3,4,5}
            \path (I-\source) edge[->] (N-\dest);

    \foreach \source in {1,2,6}
        \path (N-\source) edge[->] (O);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]