# Drawing an echo state network

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I've already asked a question for [drawing nodes in ring form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188210/draw-nodes-in-ring-form/188238#188238) but this one here seems to be much more sophisticated.

Is there an "easy way" to draw such a network in LaTeX?

[image]

It does not have to look like this but it should resemble the illustration.

Comment: There's nothing here you could not do in any of the TeX-friendly graphics tools like TikZ, Asymptote, or Metapost.  Take your pick.  Or you could try something like Inkscape and export to a graphic format.  The illustration you have shared looks like something done with TikZ.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: @cfr I will provide a MWE asap. I'm at work right now. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a snippet of code which I think illustrates the major points for creating
the sort of illustration that you want.

A word of caution:  I've cheated a bit in the code (because I'm lazy).  I'll try
to explain the *cheats* and what you need to do to avoid them or take advantage
of them.

But first, here's a particial example of the sort of illustration you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\let\@xp\expandafter
\newcommand\xtractp{\ae@xtractp}
\def\ae@xtractp#1(#2){\def#1{#2}}

%% command to assist in drawing parallel lines out of nodes
\newcommand\shiftdraw{\ae@shiftdraw}
\def\ae@shiftdraw[shift by=#1,#2] (#3) -- (#4);{%%
      \path let \p1=($(#4)-(#3)$),
                \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)},
                \n2={\n1+180},
                \n3={\n1+90},
                \n4={#1*cos(\n3)},
                \n5={#1*sin(\n3)}
            in
            [draw,#2] ([yshift=\n5,xshift=\n4]#3.\n1) -- ([yshift=\n5,xshift=\n4]#4.\n2);
}

%% commands to assist in drawing the blob
\newcommand\drawblob{\ae@blob}
\def\set@path#1\@nil#2\@nil{\path#2#1;}
\def\ae@blob#1{%%
  \let\ae@blob@path\relax{}%%
  \foreach \myn in {1,...,#1}
  {
    \ifx\ae@blob@path\relax
      \xdef\ae@blob@path{(b\myn)}%%
    \else
      \xdef\ae@blob@path{\ae@blob@path .. (b\myn)}%%
    \fi
   %%\node (N\myn) at (b\myn) {N\myn};
  }
  \@xp\set@path\ae@blob@path\@nil[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true,fill=gray!80,opacity=0.90]\@nil}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cn/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2.5pt,outer sep=1.75pt},>=Stealth]

  \node (win) at (-2.5,0.75) {};
  \node (yn) at (8,2)  {yn};
  \path (yn) -- ++(1,0)   node[draw,circle] (E)    {$-$}  
             -- ++(0,3)   node              (yt)   {yt}    
             -- ++(-1,-1) node              (wout) {wout};

  \def\myc{0}
  \foreach \myq in {(0,0),
                    (0.5,2), 
                    (1,3),
                    (2,3.5),
                    (4,3),
                    (3.5,1),
                    (3.7,-1),
                    (2,-0.5)}
  {
     \expandafter\xtractp\expandafter\myp\myq    
     \xdef\myc{\number\numexpr\myc+1}
     \coordinate (c\myc) at (\myp);
     \coordinate (b\myc) at ($(\myp)!-0.6cm!(2,1)$);
     %% \draw[->] (2,1) -- (b\myc);
  }

  %% drawing
  \draw[line width=4pt,black!80,->] (win) to[out=30,in=150] (yn);

  \drawblob{8}

  \foreach \myp in {-1,0,1}
  {
    \node[inner sep=2.5pt,outer sep=1.75pt,draw,circle] (LN\myp) at (-3,\myp) {};
    \draw[gray,->] (LN\myp) -- ++(30:1.35cm);
    \draw[gray,->] (LN\myp) -- ++(-30:1.35cm);
  }

  \draw[->] (yt) -- (E);
  \draw[->] (E) -- ++(0,-2) -- ++(-3,0) -- (wout);


  \foreach \myc in {1,...,8}
  {
     \node[circle,inner sep=2.5pt,outer sep=1.75pt,draw] (n\myc) at (c\myc) {};
  }

  \draw[looseness=8,->] (n2) to[out=100,in=160] (n2);
  \draw[->] (n2) -- (n3);
  \shiftdraw[shift by=2pt,->] (n3) -- (n4);
  \shiftdraw[shift by=-2pt,<-] (n3) -- (n4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When drawing illustrations in LaTeX, you have several choices.  My two favorite
choices are `TikZ` and `pstricks`.  Everything here can be accomplished using
`TikZ`.  Both `TikZ` and `pstricks` are *suites* of packages and provide a lot
of power.  As such, there is a concomitant learning curve.  Choose one, stick
with it, and learn it well. I do not recommend switching between the two unless
you want your head to explode:  they have similar approaches, somewhat
different philosophies, and subtle, but salient, differences in their syntax.
Both are well documented.  But the documentation for `pstricks` is spread over
multiple files.  The documentation for `TikZ` is by-and-large all contained
within one pdf-document.

Everything is drawn within a `tikzpicture` environment.

Most of what you want to be able to do in the picture can be achieved by 
creating `nodes` and/or `coordinates` and `drawing` along `paths` between them.

A `coordinate` and `node` are very similar.  It can be useful to think of a
`coordinate` as a dimensionless `node`.  `nodes` have a somewhat ellaborate
anatomy.  Relevant to the above example, `nodes` have the following features:

- `shape`
- `inner sep`
- `outer sep`

The default `shape` for a `node` is a `rectangle`.

The first thing you should notice in `tikzpicture` is the line:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[cn/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2.5pt,outer sep=1.75pt},>=Stealth]
```

I'm doing two things here.

- `cn` is a *custom node* `style` that I create.

This saves time and allows for quick and easy changes (if so desired).  For
the *custom node* I set the three features mentioned above.  I also add `draw`
which is a command to make visible the shape of the node.

The thing I'm doing on this line is setting the type of arrow to use throughout
the picture.  I'm using `Stealth` and because of this I had to load the `TikZ`
library, `arrows.meta`.   (I use no other features of this library.)

I let you read the documentation on the syntax for `nodes` (it's a bit more
involved than what I'm suggesting here).  But this is the syntax I'm using here:

```
\node (<node-name>) at (<node location>) {<node content>};
```

What's absolutely essential here is the `<node content>`.  You can leave the
brackets empty, but you must supply them.  Also notice that all `TikZ` commands
terminate in `;`.   The `<node location>` can be a Cartesian coordinate `(x,y)`,
a polar coordinate `(angle:radius)`, or the name of another `node` or `coordinate`.

The first two things I do is create two nodes named `win` and `yn`; only for
node `yn` do I provide content.

The next thing you see is a `\path`.  Paths are the backbone of most of what
happens in a `TikZ` picture.  (In fact, nodes and coordinates are just
particular kinds of paths.)  I use a `\path` command to help create the
triangular path on the right hand side of the picture

[image]

```
\draw[->] (yt) -- (E);
\draw[->] (E) -- ++(0,-2) -- ++(-3,0) -- (wout);
```

Points along the path are connected by `--`.  The `++` notation allows me to
apply a *vector* to the previously plotted point to move the *brush* to the next
point. Along the path, I define three nodes: `E`, `yt`, and `wout`.

The next segment of code is perhaps a bit more complicated than necessary, but I
was lazy (as mentioned above).  I want to create the blob in the middle of the
picture.  To do this, I use the `TikZ` library `hobby`.  (As mentioned above
almost all of the `TikZ` suite is explained in its manual.  `hobby` is an
exception to this rule.  Its documentation is found in `hobby_doc` which you can
access with `texdoc`.)

A couple of things are going on here.  I use a `\foreach` loop to cycle over the
coordinates for the points to be contained in the blob.  The problem is
that the macro `\coordinate` looks for explicitly written `(` and `)`.  So,
I wrote a macro, `\xtractp`, to extract the `x` and `y` coordinate from within the
parentheses and assign them to `\myp`.  You don't have to use this portion
of the code.  All you have to do is for each point in the blob is create
coordinates as

```
\coordinate (c1) at (0,0);  
\coordinate (c2) at (0.5,2);
\coordinate (c3) at (1,3);
```

We want the blob to form a border around these points so I chose an
arbitrary point, `(2,1)`, in the middle of the blob as reference to create
the border points of the blob.

```
\coordinate (b1) at ($(c1)!-0.6cm!(2.1)$)
\coordinate (b2) at ($(c2)!-0.6cm!(2.1)$)
```

The syntax `($(<point a>)!<dim>!(<point b>)$)` comes from the `TikZ` library
`calc`.  This tells `TikZ` to create a new point along the vector formed by
`<point b> - <point a>` at a distance of `<dim>` from `<point a>`.

Then I draw the blob.  Here I really cheat.  I created a macro to handle
the code for drawing the blob.  By long hand what you would need to do is
the following:

```
\path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true,fill=gray!80,opacity=0.90]
     (b1) .. (b2) .. (b3) .. (b4) .. (b5) .. (b6) .. (b7) .. (b8);
```

This syntax is explained in the documentation for the `hobby` library.

[image]

Actually before I draw the blob I draw a line from nodes `win` to `yn`.
The order is important to get the lay-over effect.  Also, this is the
reason I set the `opacity=0.90` when drawing the blob.

[image]

In the next portion of code I draw the crossing arrows on the left hand
side.  I use a `\foreach` loop for facilitate this.  I also use both the
`++` and polar coordinates to get the arrows pointing in the correct
direction.

[image]

I think the rest of the code is fairly self evident except for, perhaps,
the last four lines:

```
  \draw[looseness=8,->] (n2) to[out=100,in=160] (n2);
  \draw[->] (n2) -- (n3);
  \shiftdraw[shift by=2pt,->] (n3) -- (n4);
  \shiftdraw[shift by=-2pt,<-] (n3) -- (n4);
```

These lines are to draw the connections between the circles in the blob.

[image]

```
  \draw[looseness=8,->] (n2) to[out=100,in=160] (n2);
```

Draws the arrow originating from and pointing back to the circle.  Play
with the `looseness` to create a tighter and looser loop.

In the last two lines, I create another macro to create the parallel arrows
between nodes.  This is one you'll probably want to use.  The syntax here
is fairly powerful.  I recommend that you read up on this syntax in the
`TikZ` manual.

```
\newcommand\shiftdraw{\ae@shiftdraw}
\def\ae@shiftdraw[shift by=#1,#2] (#3) -- (#4);{%%
      \path let \p1=($(#4)-(#3)$),
                \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)},
                \n2={\n1+180},
                \n3={\n1+90},
                \n4={#1*cos(\n3)},
                \n5={#1*sin(\n3)}
            in
            [draw,#2] ([yshift=\n5,xshift=\n4]#3.\n1) -- ([yshift=\n5,xshift=\n4]#4.\n2);
}
```

I *fake* a key word at the beginning of this command.  In other words,
you **must**
have `shift by=` as the text that immediately follows `\shiftdraw[`.  Also,
whether or not you want to pass optional commands on to the path, you must
follow the first argument with a comma.

A final point about `inner sep` and `outer sep`.

The `inner sep` creates a *minimum* size for a node.  If the node's content is too large to fit within the *minimum* size, `TikZ` will expand the size of the node.

`outer sep` is a bit more obscure, but very salient to this problem.  It is the `outer sep` which allows the arrows to approach, but not go right up to, the drawn border of the node.

Comment: I'm not entirely happy with the `\shiftdraw` macro.  I posted a question [about whether there's a better approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191141/22413).

Comment: Wow, that is awesome and worked right on! Thank you very much I didn't expect to get such a huge example!